# Geolocation, map and polygon intersection?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, geolocation, bing-maps, google-earth

I need to retrieve the latitude and longitude coordinates of the intersection of a polygon with the street (look the blue point on the edge of the circle. [image here!!!](http://themoonlightproduction.com/lukas/share/so.png)) 
I need this data in order to calculate the road length from center of the circle, to its edge). Does anybody know if this task is possible, and if yes which technology allows for doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

This works only if you have the vector data of all streets. This does not work with an image (jpg bmp).

When you have the vector data, you do a simple circle with line intersection, which you have learned in school.
You might transform the vectors first to a cartesian x,y plane such that you dont use latitude, longitude from the street vectors.

vector data, you can get for free from OpenStreetMap, or from TomTom or NavTeq when it is a huge project. Sometimes the state provides this data, too.

A common data format for such vector data is the ESRI shp file format. (.shp)

Comment: Thanks Alex! Very clever way of solving this problem :). However, I found another way even simpler, using the google maps and google directions API. I "baked" the location (lat,long) of points located at perimeter of the circle  using trigonometric functions. After, I calculated the distance to each of the point using the google directions API. (I discarded all points that the request could not be calculated). The tricky part of this task was asynch requests to g.directions Api. Finally, I used synchronous requests.

Comment: You, also  can use google earth, and by hand draw a polygon  along the road. This gives you the road distance too.